# escaping special characters in a JSON response for JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have looked at dozens of pages of answers, but I can't find this.

I have a page which lets people create any number of profiles and add tools to those profiles.  They can give their profile any name and here is the problem. The solution below works, but it is very ugly. Here has to be a better way to do this.

```
var getProfile = jQuery.post('${pageContext.request.contextPath}/JSON?action=preferredTools&profileName='+cleanProfile, function(tool){},"json"); 
 getProfile.done(function(tool){ 
 uncheckAll();        // this is to remove any tools that may already be showing from the previous profile
 document.getElementById("formProfileName").value=rawProfileName;

 var profileName = rawProfileName.replace("\\", "\\\\").replace(/~/g,"\\~").replace(/!/g,"\\!").replace(/@/g, "\\@")
                                .replace(/\#/g, "\\#").replace(/\\$/g,"\\$").replace(/%/g,"\\%").replace(/\^/g,"\\^")
                                .replace(/\&/g,"\\&").replace(/\*/g,"\\*").replace(/\(/g,"\\(").replace(/\)/g,"\\)").replace(/_/g,"\\_")
                                .replace(/-/g,"\\-").replace(/\+/g,"\\+").replace(/\=/g,"\\=").replace(/\[/g,"\\[").replace(/\]/g,"\\]")
                                .replace(/\{/g,"\\{").replace(/\}/g,"\\}").replace(/\|/g,"\\|").replace(/\;/g,"\\;").replace(/\:/g,"\\:")
                                .replace(/\'/g,"\\'").replace(/\,/g,"\\,").replace(/\./g,"\\.").replace(/\?/g,"\\?")
                                .replace(/\</g,"\\<").replace(/\>/g,"\\>").replace(/\`/g,"\\`").replace(/\/ /g,"\\/");

$('#profile_'+profileName).prop("checked", true);
```

I tried using escape(rawProfileName) where rawProfileName = "brita's profile" but it gives this error message.

```
Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #profile_brita%2527s%20profile
throw new Error( "Syntax error, unrecognized expression: " + msg );
```

Same thing if I use ProfileName = $('').text(profileName).html();

Comment: I just popped open the console, ran the code `escape("brita's profile")` and it worked great... are you sure some other code isn't intervening?

Comment: the problem is when the jquery looks for the id  to mark it as checked.

Comment: the problem is when the jquery looks for the id  to mark it as checked.  
    $('#profile_'+profileName).prop("checked", true); 
 when profileName is brita's profile and it is parsed to 
    brita%2527s%20profile 
There is an error.   

However brita\%27s profile works just fine.  this is what my ugly code produces.

Comment: have you considered creating a slug to deal with this? if you have the potential for special characters in a field it can often be easier to use a slug for your page references and keep the raw title only for printing directly

Comment: Thanks Jeff, I tried googling a slug for page references and only found information for wordpress.  If you could point me in the right direction I would appreciate it.  Thanks, Brita

Comment: So a slug is more of a concept you can implement. When something has a human-readable title and also needs a way to reference it based on the title without special chars (for a filename, url, classname, etc) you should create a slug and store them both. the slug is a version of the title stripped of spaces special characters. As long as they are both attached to the same object, you can use one to get the other when needed.